# 3-х колоночная резиновая верстка (контент должен грузится первым, потом сайдбары)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте. Мне нужна 3-х колоночная резиновая верстка: Левый и правый сайдбар фиксированной ширины, контент - резиновый. Внизу футер.

Обязательно, нужно чтобы сначала контент загружался, потом сайдбары, т.е. если брать нумерацию Left sidebar - 1, Content - 2, Right sidebar - 3, то желаемый порядок блоков 2-1-3 (ниже приведен HTML) или 2-3-1, в крайнем случае 1-2-3 (обычно используется 1-3-2, мне такой вариант не подходит, так как нужно чтобы правый сайдбар на мобильной версии шёл после контента).

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <section class="middle clr">
    <section id="block-2" class="content">Content</section>
    <aside id="block-1" class="left">Left sidebar</aside>
    <aside  id="block-3" class="right">Right sidebar</aside>
  </section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</main>
```

Желательна поддержка старых браузеров.

Вариант с абсолютным позиционированием рассматривал, но там проблема с футером - нужно постоянно находить высоту наибольшего блока и устанавливать высоту контейнера... но если js отключен (понятно что таких очень редко), то всё на куче...., иногда проблемы с вычислением высоты блоков, особенно если на странице js анимированные/подгружаемые элементы...

Comment: нет человека, который знает всё... ставить минусы довольно просто, ума много не надо, можно даже не читая, и не вникая в проблему, как многие делают... элементарно, даже скинуть ссылку, сайт, где такое реализовано, но это значительно тяжелее, чем минус поставить... посмотрел куча мануалов по 3-х колоночной вёрстке - всё однотипно, сам часто их использую... Но пришлось сейчас переделывать один аналитический сайт под мобильную вёрстку, где положение каждого элемента имеет очень большую роль и стандартные способы не подходят...

Comment: Добрый день, @guitarhero! Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на следующий вопрос на Мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clr:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

main {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #eee;
}

aside {
  position: relative;
  /* Чтоб z-index сработал */
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Чтоб было выделение текста, так как aside будет прятаться под .content, размещенный перед ним */
}

.middle {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Не дает колонкам уходить друг под друга. Однако, работая с меди запросами, нужно будет убрать данный стиль для более низких разрешений, где нужно будет сайдбары переместить вниз. */
}

.middle>aside,
.middle>section {
  white-space: normal;
  /* Нормализует перенос строк текста. Без него, весь текст пойдет одной сплошной строкой */
}

.content {
  padding: 0 230px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Задается, чтоб блок расположился между 2 float-ами */
  background: #00CC334D;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -200px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .middle {
    white-space: normal;
  }
  .content {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  aside {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:420px) {
  aside {
    width: 100%;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <section class="middle clr">
    <section class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</section>
    <aside class="left">Left sidebar</aside>
    <aside class="right">Right sidebar</aside>
  </section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</main>
```

По цифрам не очень то и понятно, но, вроде правильно. Верстка через float будет работать во всех браузерах. Можно и flexbox использовать, но, это на любителя.

Comment: дописал в вопросе то, что мне нужно. Согласно моей нумерации, у вас загрузка блоков 1-2-3.т.е. сайдбар, потом контент, потом сайдбар. мне бы хотелось чтобы сначала контент, а потом сайдбары...

Comment: Внес правки, теперь контент идет вначале.

Comment: Этот способ работает до тех пора, пока content в одну строку, если больше, то правый sidebar уходит вниз https://fiddle.jshell.net/80p80hag/

Comment: Внес правки, теперь с высотой порядок.

Comment: Спасибо. сделал несколько тестов, в некоторых случаях сайдбары скидывает вниз, но ваша идея понятна, немного допилю и будет нормально... Первый раз встретил, чтобы средний блок имел "display: inline-block;", даже не думал об этом... я так понимаю white-space имеет здесь немаловажный факт, или я ошибаюсь... если можете,добавте краткое пояснение в ответ или ссылку

Comment: Сайдбары скидывает вниз, когда ширина контента будет слишком маленькой, чтоб уместить одно слово. Обычно до этого не доходит, так как при сужении экрана, боковые блоки уходят вниз, а контент растягивают по ширине окна, убирая `padding`. Так же добавил описание к некоторым стилям. Я обычно не использую 3-х колоночную верстку, поэтому потестируйте результат. Сейчас еще добавлю медиа-запрос, чтоб вы видели трансформацию.